# Graph Relatives for Tessellation of the Hyperbolic Plane

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, tiling

I'm trying to get into the theory about the [Modular group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group). Among the "Paracompact hyperbolic uniform tilings in [∞,3] family" in the section "Tessellation of the hyperbolic plane" I found the [Order-3 apeirogonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-3_apeirogonal_tiling):

[image]
[image]

The figure reminded my on [Frucht's graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht_graph),
which seems to have the similar structural features.

> Are there also graphs for the other tilings?

Comment: The dual graph of the tiling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph.

Comment: @LeeMosher Which tiling would this be at the Wiki page?

Comment: What I mean is that the dual graph of the tiling is a general concept that applies to all tilings. Your example is the dual graph to the tiling of the hyperbolic plane by ideal triangles also known as $(\infty,\infty,\infty)$ triangles.

Comment: @LeeMosher And the graph related to the dual tiling is the dual of Frucht's graph?

Comment: I do not know of any analogue's of Frucht's graph in general.